# $\sup_x(y \cdot f(x)+b(x)-1/2\lVert f(x) \rVert^2)$ convex and regular with respect to $y$?

Tags: convex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I'm studying the article "Brenier, Y. (1987) Décomposition polaire et réarrangement monotone des champs de vecteurs" (polar factorization and monotone rearrangement of vector-valued functions).

In this work one function is build which is expected to have some properties:

let $f$ be a function from some compact space S, $f:S \mapsto S$.
$f$ is supposed to be bounded, Rieman-integrable and a Borel function.
let $b$ a measurable and bounded function.
let $g(y)=\sup_x(y \cdot f(x)+b(x)-1/2\lVert f(x) \rVert^2)$ for $y \in S \bigcup f(S)$ (NB I'm unsure for $\bigcup$. It may be $\bigcap$).
The assertion is made that $g$ is convex, lipschitz continue and differentiable but no proof is given. I understand that it is most certainly an immediate result for an expert in the field, which I'm not.

How can these properties be proven?

I trivially started from the definition of convexity:
$g(ty_0+(1-t)y_1) = \sup_x(ty_0 \cdot f(x)+(1-t)y_1 \cdot f(x)+b(x)-1/2\lVert f(x) \rVert^2)$ but I don't know how to handle that further, when taking the supremum.

I also gave a try with $S$ a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$, $b=0$ and $f$ differentiable. I've got two extremum for $y \cdot f(x)-1/2\lVert f(x) \rVert^2$: $f'(x)=0$ and $y=f(x)$. Setting $z=f(x)$, I can see trivially that the second one is a maximum, then $g(y)=1/2y^2$ which has the desired properties. But, so far, it does not give me more insight for the more general version.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.